# Can HERE indoor positioning API work with BLE tags?

Tags: here-api

Does indoor positioning/tracking work with BLE tags? The indoor positioning API seems to require a mobile phone with the mobile SDK installed.

What about Bluetooth Low Energy tags that's more lightweight?

Answer (score 0):

HERE Indoor Positioning uses either Bluetooth (Android, iOS) or WiFi (Android) to support indoor positioning.

Bluetooth LE beacons are supported. Please learn about requirements for beacons from HERE Indoor Positioning Installation Guide (https://indoor.here.com/docs/Indoor_Positioning_Installation_Guide.pdf). The beacon requirements are in Chapter 4.

HERE Indoor Positioning is mobile centric, i.e. position estimation takes place in a device to provide highly responsive, zero-latency location, because there is no network latency. That is why an app embedding HERE Mobile SDK is required.

Please visit https://indoor.here.com for further information.